# How get Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) from OnPreviewMouseUp of a control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to get information if ctrl is being held while clicking in a control.

I can get this info just fine in OnKeyUp but I need to get this info from MouseUp

any directions are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MouseButtonEventArgs` does indeed not have any information about which keys are down, but you can use `System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown()`, to determine that information from within any event handler (or anywhere in your application, for that matter).

For example:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

....

private void OnPreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var isLeftControlUp = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)
}
```